# Sencha Touch 2 Ext.util.Geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, extjs, sencha-touch-2

how can I get latitude and longitude outside created object?
I've made new object of Ext.util.Geolocation, updated it, and now I'm trying to get Latitude and Longitude values outside the object, but it shows me 'null'.
Code:

```
var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
    autoUpdate: false,
    listeners: {
        locationupdate: function(geo) {
            //alert('New latitude: ' + geo.getLatitude());
        },
        locationerror: function(geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
            if(bTimeout){
                alert('Timeout occurred.');
            } else {
                alert('Error occurred.');
            }
        }
    }
});

geo.updateLocation();
//geo.fireEvent('locationupdate');

alert(geo.getLatitude()); // it shows null
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with geo.updateLocation();

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because it takes some time to get your location.

You should try to get the latitude and the longitude within the `locationupdate` callback function.

If you want to access it outside, just make sure that geo exists

```
if (geo) { alert(geo.getLatitude()); }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Same here. Was an answer to this ever found?

Comment: You can't be sure geo isn't equal to null before the first update has happened so do whatever you want to do in the locationupdate callback function.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a timing issue - obtaining the location is not synchronous, therefore you can not access it outside the `locationupdate` callback function, at least until it has been initialized.

You should do whatever you need to do inside that callback (e.g. call another function passing in the latitude if it needs)...

```
    ...
    listeners: {
        locationupdate: function(geo) {
            yourCallbackFunction(geo.getLatitude());
    },
    ...
```

If you really need to use it outside that callback, then in the worst case you can do something like:

```
var latitude; //will store latitude when ready..
var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
    autoUpdate: false,
    listeners: {
        locationupdate: function(geo) {
            latitude = geo.getLatitude();
        }
    }
});
geo.updateLocation();

//waits until latitude exists then does something..
var untilLatThere = setInterval(function(){
    if(latitude) {
        alert(latitude); //alerts a valid value..
        clearInterval(untilLatThere);
    }
}, 100);
```